# React-Native: Real-Time json data

Tags: javascript, react-native

I am showing the data in the listView from this url
https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users
I want the `listView` to act as real-time data, it should automatically update the `json`,
What is the best way to implement it? Please give some example
Currently i am repeating the request over some time but that is not efficient, So it would be really helpful if someone will provide an example or something.